# Why is it wrong

Tags: python

when input it
it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/goncas.py", line 4, in <module>
    print("A pessoa que tem "+ idade2 +" e mais velha que a pessoa que tem "+ idade)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

```
age = int(input("Insira a sua idade"))
age2 = int(input("Insira a outra idade"))

if age <= age2:
    print("The person who has "+ age2 +" is older then the person that has "+ age)
elif age >= age2:
    print("The person who has "+ age +" is older then the person that has "+ age2)
else:
    print("Invalid data")
```

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function str(ageX), as the integer values can not converted to strings implicitly. (or don't cast it to int before)

```
print("The person who has "+ str(age2) +" is older then the person that has "+ str(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this :

```
print("The person who has "+ str(age2) +" is older then the person that has "+ str(age))
```

Because you try to add str object to int object. So python debugger can't define this operation.